# Upgrading 100+ sites with same schema

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, office-365

I have an application with over 100 site collections. Each site collection has a root site, and all of them have exactly the same schema.

Now I need to make a change to a field in a list that these sites have. Is there a way to apply the change to them all at once, so that I don't have to deploy a solution to a couple hundred different sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is your friend here. You can iterate over the sites, webs, and lists to make your schema change.

Comment: Been thinking about that. I'm coming up with a script that we can use in Sharepoint Online.

Comment: As coincidence would have it, I just needed to do something similar: http://sympmarc.com/2013/09/24/item-modified-by-value-doesnt-change-fixing-a-damaged-column-schema/